# How can I filter records according to current date?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, date

I am implementing a functionality I am storing date in String form and get current date in string from using LocalDate function so I want to compare both dates, I want to fetched only current date records.

No error found but record could not fetch.

```
  public ArrayList<Followup_Model> followup_reminder (ArrayList<Followup_Model> followup_Model_list) {
    if (followup_Model_list == null) {
        followup_Model_list = new ArrayList<>();
    }
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getReadableDatabase();
    DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy/MM/dd");
    LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.now();
    String Today = dtf.format(localDate);
    Cursor followup_output = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + Table_Name_Followup +
            " WHERE CREATEDBY = '1' AND CHECKED = '1' AND STARTDATE = " + Today +
            " ORDER BY REMINDER ASC",null);
```

Comment: try to surround the date with single quotes

Comment: @ScaryWombat date is not fixed it is coming into variable how can I put it into single quotes

Comment: `AND STARTDATE = '" + Today + "'" + ` or better to use a PreparedStatement and use paramaters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just copy and Paste.

```
public ArrayList<Followup_Model> followup_reminder (ArrayList<Followup_Model> 
 followup_Model_list) {
    if (followup_Model_list == null) {
        followup_Model_list = new ArrayList<>();
    }
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getReadableDatabase();
    DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy/MM/dd");
    LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.now();
    String Today = dtf.format(localDate);
    Cursor followup_output = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + Table_Name_Followup +
            " WHERE CREATEDBY = '1' AND CHECKED = '1' AND STARTDATE = '" + Today + "'" +
            " ORDER BY REMINDER ASC",null);
```